# Keep images flowing horizontally with hidden overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images inside a containing DIV.  I have the DIV absolutely positioned to the right of its container and I want it so that if the number of images exceeds the width of the parent container they flow horizontally still, but are hidden (so I can scroll the containing div later)

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="propertyThumbnails">
        <a href="pic1" class=""></a>
        <a href="pic1" class=""></a>
        <a href="pic1" class=""></a>
        <a href="pic1" class=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xWcXt/) to demonstrate this, to reiterate what I want is for the images to flow horizontally only, and any that go outside the parent container are hidden (ill then scroll the propertyThumbnails container later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#propertyThumbnails {
    background: #666;
    height: 80px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xWcXt/3/